# Where to set up the range of page for the pagination in Magento?

Tags: magento, pagination

I know I already did it, it is somewhere in the backend... but can't remember where.

I need to limit the number of page displayed by the paginator

show 5 pages:

```
[1] - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 >
```

show 10 pages:

```
[1] - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 >
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change them under the

**System -> configuration -> General -> Design -> pagination..**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> **Configuration** > **System** > **Catalog** > *Frontend*

[image]